# Laravel 5.4 Api Route 401

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I built a new laravel 5.4 project.

I tried to do the steps below in my api route, but somehow they do not work.

In my app.js file I have this ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/postStream',
    type: 'post',
    data: { imgData: imgData },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

My Api Route looks like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function()
{
    Route::post('postStream', ['as' => 'image', 'uses' => 'ApiController@postStream']);
});
```

And my controller:

```
public function postStream(Request $request)
{
    $imgData = $request->imgData;
    ...
}
```

But I get this error in my chrome dev console:

```
POST http://localhost/app/public/api/postStream 401 (Unauthorized)
```

And in the network tools this:

```
{error: "Unauthenticated."}
error
:
"Unauthenticated."
```

I guess I am somewhat not authentificated, but I do not know how to make that happen this way.

Comment: Can this help you? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/many-time-401-unauthorized-on-ajax-requests

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the correct endpoint ? My guess is http request should go to  http://localhost/api/postStream.

Comment: You need to pass the access token if you are using `['middleware' => 'auth:api']`. Follow the steps of creating API, securing API and requesting API key. First of all you need to get access key and pass that with ajax call. I am using `Passport` to provide authentication to my API. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: @webDev hmm ok do you know a tutorial which explains this further? this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport ?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't work because your route is protected by `auth:api`, which returns `401 unauthorized`. The only way to go through `auth:api` is to send your authentication token with every single request

```
var token = <?php json_encode(Auth::user()->api_token); ?>; //if you are using api_token

$.ajax({
    url: 'api/postStream',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    type: 'post',
    ...
});
```

The way you get your token is entirely up to you. You could use Passport or simply the easiest solution which is adding api_token to your users table.

If you are going for the cheapest solution, you can follow this post: https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

Comment: Hi I was away for a couple of days and could not responed to you so I built following https://kopy.io/WIZp1 how excatly does the ajax header have to look like ? I do not get the `Bearer` thing

Comment: You need an api token to 'bear' the authorization. I gave you a link to see how to add api_token to your users. Because you need it for authentication.